# Sending Array to a Single Process

Tags: mpi

I have an array with size nx*ny. The data in the array is in nrows*ncols processes. I want to send all the various parts of the array to a single array in a single process, say process 0.

I do it this way: I perform two do loops one the on nrows with variable x and another one inside that on the ncols with variable y. In each loop I find the process that has the row and coloumn same as x and y and use mpi_isend to send the data to process 0 and after that, again inside the same loop process 0 recevies the subarray by mpi_irecv.

I actually tried this and the problem is process 0 keeps receiving data that are not still sent! I even tried using mpi_barrier without success. Below is my code. Can anyone help me please? Thanks.

```
do x=0,grid%nrows
  do y=0,grid%ncols

    ! Finding the relevant process and sending
    if ((grid%row==x) .and. (grid%col==y)) then
      call MPI_ISEND(tempp,ctot,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,0, &
        & grid%proc,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
    end if

    ! Process 0 receives data
    if (grid%proc==0) then
      call MPI_IRECV(temp0(2*grid%xl:2*grid%xl+2*grid%mx-1, &
        & :,1:size(v%a,4)), &
        & ctot,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, &
        & x*grid%ncols+y,x*grid%ncols+y,MPI_COMM_WORLD,stat,ierr)
    end if

  end do
end do
```

Comment: Using non-blocking communication with array sections often results in undefined behaviour. Do not use non-blocking operations with array sections.

Answer (score 0):

[`mpi_Irecv`](http://mpi.deino.net/mpi_functions/MPI_Irecv.html) and [`mpi_Isend`](http://mpi.deino.net/mpi_functions/MPI_Isend.html) are non-blocking functions. This means, that these function calls return before the transmission is completed. To solve your problem, you can either

- use the blocking versions, [`mpi_Recv`](http://mpi.deino.net/mpi_functions/MPI_Recv.html) and [`mpi_Send`](http://mpi.deino.net/mpi_functions/MPI_Send.html) or
- add [`mpi_Wait`](http://mpi.deino.net/mpi_functions/MPI_Wait.html) calls to your solution to wait for the non-blocking calls to finish.

Comment: Non-blocking operations should **not** be used with non-contiguous array sections such as the one in the `MPI_RECV` call unless one uses the `mpi_f08` interface of MPI-3.0 and the implementation supports safely passing array sections.